# Laravel 5.2 - Can You Create A Relationship Between A Pivot Table And A Table It's Not Pivoting For?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a pivot table called **user_store**.  It's used to establish a many to many relationship between the **users** table and the **stores** table and looks something like this:

```
user_id - int
store_id - int
user_age_range - string
```

I have another table called **user_memberships**.  It's columns look like:

```
user_id - int
store_id - int
membership_cost - decimal
membership_expiration - date
```

I need to establish a relationship between the **user_memberships** table and the **user_store** pivot table using the *user_id* and *store_id* columns present in both tables.

How would I do this when the **user_store** table does not have its own model (since it's a pivot table)?